# Difficult css shape

Tags: html, css, transform, css-shapes

Is it possible to make this shape with a single html element?

I want to use it for cropping images, that's why it would be easier if it was only one element

[image]

Comment: You might want to add an image of the shape or any example code.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to make that shape using a single element?

**YES**

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 140px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 110%;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
}
div:before {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  top: -40px;
}
div:after {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  bottom: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note:** *Some tweaking may need to be done to get it as you want, but you get the idea.*

Would I recommend using it for cropping? No. To create this shape the `:before` and `:after` elements are white (the background colour) so this would only work if you had a plain background. Its doable but not the best.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

If you are looking to use a solid colour background, you could look to use a border on some pseudo elements.

For a quick demo:

```css
div {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
div:before, div:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
div:before{
    top:0;
    border-right:300px solid transparent;
    border-top:100px solid white;    
}
div:after{
    bottom:0;
    border-right:300px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:50px solid white;    
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

---

## Solution 2

An alternative would be to use perspective and rotation (note. prefixing would be required):

```css
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(-20deg);
    margin-top:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300"/>
</div>
```

---

## Alternatives

Further alternatives include:

- SVG
- Clip-path (although [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) isn't brilliant)